# I want to compare a record with the substring of record from another table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a master table where it has record of parts with different types but not defined in the same table. Instead we have another table called t_pfx where part types are defined based on their prefixes provided t_pfx and master table is not related. lets say part id starts from E20xxxxxx, E21xxxx..... to E99xxxxx are components are defined in t_pfx.

I write a query something like this

```
select part_id where status in ('OBS','INACT') order by last_mod_date asc;
```

But above query will select all the type of parts.

I need to query with comparison, if part ids starts with E20xxxx, E21xxxx..... E99xxxxx should only be extracted. Could you please anyone help me with this

Comment: Isn't  this what you basically want - `where part_id between 20000000 and 99999999`?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what i am looking for. but  actually part id starts from E20000000 to E9999999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is regular expressions:

```
where status in ('OBS', 'INACT') and
      regexp_like(part_id, '^E[2-9][0-9]')
```

If you know the second and third positions are always digits, you can also do something like this:

```
where status in ('OBS', 'INACT') and
      (part_id >= 'E20' AND
       part_id < 'E9:'
      )
```

The colon happens to be the Ascii character immediately following `'9'`.  The advantage to this method is that it can take advantage of an index that includes `part_id`.

Comment: Considering both the methods, series of parts like from E20xxxx to E62xxx and E65XXXX to E78xXXX are only components. so I tried the same query with small modification `where status in ('OBS', 'INACT') and
      (part_id >= 'E20' AND
       part_id < 'E62'
      ) or (part_id >= 'E65' AND
       part_id < 'E78'
      )`. but it did not work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Use `like operator` with `OR condition`

```
select part_id from tablename
where status in ('OBS','INACT') and (part_id like '20xxxx%' or part_id like '21xxxx%' or 
part_id like '99xxxxx%')
order by last_mod_date asc
```

Comment: `select part_id from tablename
where status in ('OBS','INACT') and (part_id like '20xxxx%' or part_id like '21xxxx%' or 
part_id like '99xxxxx%')
order by last_mod_date asc` yes this helps but I need to compare part id starts from 20xxxx , 21xxx till 99xxxxx. (in numbering order). this will become big query as I can see. is there any thing which can also reduce query siz also and comparing ?

Answer (score 1):

you could use regular expression in filter

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(part_id,'[^0-9]');
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... where substr(part_id,1,2) >= 20